WSL produces hundreds of messages with `hv_storvsc...` per second
I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 in WSL. Every second around 100 messages like this is written to log:
[   88.455305] hv_storvsc fd1d2cbd-ce7c-535c-966b-eb5f811c95f0: tag#12 cmd 0x28 status: scsi 0x2 srb 0x4 hv 0xc0000001

$ sudo dmesg -C ; sleep 10; dmesg | grep hv_storvsc | wc -l
1114

The net result is that the system is unusable. It's sluggish and consumes a lot of CPU, and this results in high fan use as well, so it's unbearably noisy.
What I've attempted:

Re-install the distro from scratch
Re-install WSL (disable feature in windows, restart)
wsl --update - I am at version 2.2.4
Re-install Windows 10 from scratch
Check disk for errors, both in Windows and Linux. No errors.
Replicated behaviour on brand new out of box hardware.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to solve this issue?

What are you usining for antivirus?

@amar Microsoft defender.

Someone in this thread https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9173 claimed was due to Dfender. To test it disconnect your computer from internet and shut down Defender see if that might be the reason.

@amar thanks, I'll try.

This turned out to be a bug in HyperV. This only happens after hibernation, and with kernels newer than 5.5, as a specific feature was enabled in 5.5.
The fix is to install an older kernel, or a newer kernel with this feature disabled.
For further information, I suggest to read this comment on the Github issue, and this issue for a relevant kernel that will fix the issue, as well as instructions for installing a kernel.
I went back to 5.4.0, which works flawless.

Not assuming your skill level, this is for anyone coming across the answer: Make sure you are aware of what you are doing. YOU CAN LIKELY BREAK YOUR WSL AND WINDOWS FILESYSTEMS BY MISUSING sudo COMMANDS ON DISKS
This thread suggests running a disk check on your drive through windows:

I had the same issue, and also the SSD disk usage was 100% in the task manager. It turned out also some bad sectors errors on the host's drive. It was also fixed by running a disk (C drive) check on the Windows host as admin + reboot chkdsk C: /f /r /x

In this case, the user is operating on their C drive from windows, /f locks and fixes the disk. /r locates bad sectors and recovers info on top of what /f does. /x forces dismount first and also does what /f does. Likely, you could skip the /f option. See here for more info.
This thread does also imply needing to use e2fsck from wsl after fixing the windows side, but the instructions are potentially more dangerous, as the user does not specify unmounting the disk first (required for e2fsck unless you are an expert). I would probably attempt the windows solution first and see if that is sufficient.

and then when I booted the Ubuntu distrib the root filesystem was mounted in read-only due to filesystem errors confirmed with sudo e2fsck /dev/sdd -p

Here, the user is asking e2fsck to automatically fix the parts of the filesystem that it can. I assume the user got an error attempting that step indicating that it was mounted/read only and could not be executed.

I had to repair the filesystem with sudo e2fsck /dev/sdd -y

This is potentially dangerous, the user is asking e2fsck to fix the filesystem with superuser permissions and assuming 'yes' answer to all questions. Again, the drive should be unmounted for this. I would probably do a lot more research before attempting this step myself.
Obviously you will need to replace the drive paths with ones applicable to your system as well.
An example of what I see on Windows 11 with WSL Ubuntu 22.04.3:
$ sudo dmesg | grep storvsc
[    0.324754] hv_vmbus: registering driver hv_storvsc
[    0.326620] scsi host0: storvsc_host_t
[    3.438044] hv_storvsc fd1d2cbd-ce7c-535c-966b-eb5f811c95f0: tag#831 cmd 0x2a status: scsi 0x0 srb 0x4 hv 0xc00000a1


I've ruled out hardware issues. The problem is persistent across different laptops.

@vidarlo Are you able to/have you tried on a windows 11 host? I only have access to windows 11 right now, but I was able to set up Ubuntu 22.04.3 WSL on a laptop with no issue. I see exactly one instance of the storvsc message early in boot, which I will add to my answer for reference

@DouglasB I have - and that seems to work fine, although it's of course not the exact same environment...

@vidarlo yes, I was hoping to further rule out hardware issues/narrow in on what  is different between our setups. I will try to get access to a windows 10 machine and see if I can recreate any behavior like you are seeing

@DouglasB I appreciate the effort, this has me somewhat stymified. On one computer it worked fine for ~2-3 months, before appearing,. Upon re-installing the same computer with Win10 again, it appeared after ~2 hrs. It also appears with other distros such as Debian and Kali - which is not surprising as they share kernel.

@vidarlo what kind of work are you doing in WSL? I got ahold of a windows 10 machine (few years old lenovo laptop) and it installed without issue. I will leave it running and monitor for those errors, but I feel like I may not encounter them letting it idle (unless that is all that is required to reproduce it on your end?)

They come even when idle :)

Hello.  What is version of Windows you're using? There is a quartet of numbers in the version string. Would you please post it?
